# tracking e-mail

Tags: security, gmail

Is it possible to track an email sent from a proxy site.? sent from a gmail account.can anyone provide a suitable link on how to trace the original ip of that email. or any relevant details as such. ??

Answer (score 1):

You want to look in the email header.  This link should help you out.

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-track-the-original-location-of-an-email-via-its-ip-address/

Answer (score 1):

There is a tracker called **emailTrackerPro** which can trace the IP address of the sender along with the geographic location of the sender.... But the problem is that **you need to buy** that tracker (such  a software should be made free :-p)... 
http://www.emailtrackerpro.com/